# How to recover user access to Mysql database?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp

I am working in `LAMP(Mysql)`, I wanted to allow an external ip to connect to the database but it was not possible because Mysql was using `MyISAM` storage engine, so I tried to change it to `InooDB` adding `default-storage-engine = InnoDB` inside the `[mysqld]` in the file configuration.

After restarting the service the `sysop` user lost access to `mysql`.

When I check the permissions to databases with `mysqlcheck -u sysop -p --check --databases moodle` it returns: `mysqlcheck: Error: Couldn't get table list for database moodle: Access denied for user 'sysop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But when I go to `mysql` and run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'sysop'@'localhost'` it says that I have full access to all databases. Also I have a `moodle` applications connecting with mysql using this user and I am able to fetch and Insert data from the data base `USING THE SAME USER`

I also usually connect to `mysql` by `phpMyAdmin` using `sysop` but now it returns an error: `Access denied to user 'sysop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

How is this possible? I need to access to the database.

Comment: Umm ... there is a great deal of confusion in these actions. Changing the default storage engine does not make changes to any of the databases or tables that already exist. Are you trying to connect to `sysop@localhost` from the system with MySQL installed? Or are you trying to connect from a different system?

Comment: i tried to connect as `sysop@localhost` inside the same server where it's installed. I had to  stop the service and force upgrade anyway, that's how I fixed it